# gnuplot: How to plot points over the bars of a clustered histogram?

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I'm making some speedup graphs using `histogram clustered`. For each instance, I group the speedup reached using 2,4,8,16 and 32 computers. I also use a line to indicate the "linear speedup". However, for each instance/computer, I would like also to place a `point` on top of it, to indicate a value I'm comparing my speedup to.

I've tried to use the same strategy for plotting the boxes, but using points instead. However, the points are plotted on the same place, they are not obeying the ''clustered'' spacing.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
set yrange [0:105]
set grid ytics

set style line 1 lc rgb '#0e1111' lt 1 lw 2 pt -1 ps 1.0 
set xlabel "Instance" font "sans, 18"
set ylabel "Normalized Speedup (In %)" font "sans, 18"

set style histogram clustered

plot  for [COL=2:2] 'data.dat' using COL:xticlabels(1) title columnheade lc rgbcolor "black" lt -1 fs pattern 3,\
for [COL=3:3] 'data.dat' using COL:xticlabels(1) title columnheade lc rgbcolor "black" lt -1 fs pattern 1,\
"linear.t" t "Lin" with linespoints ls 1
```

Example of data

```
0   2   4   8   16  32
ta22    65.67   37.98   38.16   30.91   19.24 
ta23    73.69   45.59   48.59   44.20   34.19
```

That's what I got. The points are what I would like to have.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/ugFhQdf]

Is it possible to have such a thing? It would also work like an error bar. However, without line and just a ''max''.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't run your code. But, based on your image, I understood you problem. 
To plot the points with you want, I created a file called `points.dat`.

```
0   2   4   8   16  32
ta22    75.67   47.98   48.16   40.91   29.24 
ta23    83.69   55.59   58.59   54.20   44.19
```

This one nothing else is that `your data + 10`.
The `gnuplot` code

```
reset                                           # Restore the default settings
set encoding utf8                               # Selects the character encoding
set terminal pngcairo size 800,500              # Generates output in png
set output 'histogram.png'                      # The filename
set grid ytics ls -1 lc 'gray'                  # Grid lines ytics only
set yrange [0:100]                              # Yrange 0 to 100 (% ?)
set style data histograms                       # Type of data: histograms
set style histogram clustered gap 1             # Type of histogram: clustered with gap 1
set style fill transparent solid 1 border lt -1 # Style: fillstyle and border

stats 'points.dat' skip 1 matrix nooutput       # Statistical summary with skip
                                                # for header and without output 

numRows = STATS_size_y              # Y size of matrix (rows)
numCols = STATS_size_x              # X size of matrix (columns)

array Value[numRows*(numCols-1)]    # Create an array based on size of data

position = 0                        # Count to position on array

# Loop for populate the array
do for [i=1:numRows]{
    do for [j=2:numCols]{
        # Statistical summary (with skip for header) at each value and without output 
        stats 'points.dat' skip 1 u j every ::i-1::i-1 nooutput
        position = position + 1         # Increase the count of position
        Value[position] = STATS_min     # Define the array-value as result of statistical analysis
    }
}

# Mapping functions: 
# i-cluster/rows (x-values),
# j-column (y-values)
# ignore the cluster name ($1)
posX(i, j) = (i - 1) + 1.0*(j - numCols + 3)/numCols        # To X-values
posY(i, j) = i == 1 ? Value[j] : Value[numCols - 1 + j]     # To Y-values

# The plot itself as newhistogram and nested loops:
# i-loop to bars and title as columnheade
# j-loop to rows (x-values)
# k-loop to columns (y-values)
plot \
    newhistogram ,\
        for [i=2:numCols]\
            'data.dat' u i:xticlabels(1) ls i-1 title columnheade,\
        for [j=1:numRows] \
            for [k=1:numCols-1] \
                '+' u (posX(j, k)):(posY(j, k)) w p pt 5 ps 0.75 lc 'black' notitle
```

produces

[image: histogram]

Comment: Hello GRSousaJr! Thank you! I tried and worked just fine =)))

Comment: Great! Don't forget to mark your question as answered.